# Android ImageView null object when trying to set Image

Tags: java, android, database, firebase

I am having difficulty setting an ImageView with a string download url that is in a user object that came from the firebase storage DB. The method setImage() is saying the Imageview is a null object and this is true as I have tried to debug it and it comes up as null. How can I resolve this. I think it has something to do with the anonymous inner class.

```
public class DashBoard extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private ArrayList<String> motivatingMessages;
    private Button gymLocations, profile,health;
    public ImageView profileImageView;
    private TextView welcome;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        showProfilePicture();
        profileImageView = findViewById(R.id.personalProfile);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dash_board);
        //getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Welcome To Bodify");
        profile = findViewById(R.id.buttonProfile);
        gymLocations = findViewById(R.id.gymFinderButton);
        health = findViewById(R.id.healthButton);
        welcome = findViewById(R.id.welcomeUser);

        final String userID = mAuth.getUid();
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child(userID);
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                if (user != null) {
                    welcome.setText("User Logged in: ");
                    welcome.append(user.getUserName());
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(DashBoard.this, "Error Occurred: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        gymLocations.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GymsNearMe.class));
            }
        });
        profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PersonalProfile.class));
            }
        });
        health.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(DashBoard.this,Health.class));
            }
        });

    }


    public void showProfilePicture() {

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        final String userID = mAuth.getUid();
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child(userID);
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                String image = user.getmImageUrl();
                setImage(image);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(DashBoard.this, "Error Occurred: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        Picasso.get().load(image).into(profileImageView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.logOut) {
            mAuth.signOut();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LogIn.class));
        }
        return true;
    }
}

enter code here
```

Comment: You probably don't have a view ID'd with `personalProfile` in your layout.

Comment: <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/personalProfile"
                        android:layout_width="173dp"
                        android:layout_height="144dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to find the view before inflating the layout:

```
profileImageView = findViewById(R.id.personalProfile);
```

move that line after the inflation so after the line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_dash_board);
```

In other words, the order of the lines should be:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_dash_board);

mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

profileImageView = findViewById(R.id.personalProfile);
showProfilePicture();
```

and you do not need to set the `mAuth` again in the `showProfilePicture`

Comment: That was exactly the problem so Now there are no errors but the image is coming up as blank I guess that is my next hurdle many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_dash_board);
profileImageView = findViewById(R.id.personalProfile);
profile = findViewById(R.id.buttonProfile);
gymLocations = findViewById(R.id.gymFinderButton);
health = findViewById(R.id.healthButton);
welcome = findViewById(R.id.welcomeUser);
showProfilePicture();
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
```

try with this order

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
        at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:682)
        at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:665)
        at com.example.bodify.DashBoard.setImage(DashBoard.java:155)
        at com.example.bodify.DashBoard$6.onDataChange(DashBoard.java:145)

Comment: I initialized first then called the method same error is occurring. It is not able to access the image view in my code for some reason maybe to do with anonymous inner class as it is asynchronous

Comment: It has nothing to do with how I am setting the Image view, I have tried 3 different ways including -> Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(user.getmImageUrl()).into(profileImageView);, But it says The image view is null this is due to the way we load database info in a async callback

Comment: It is the order of the operations that is not correct. Please checks my answer